# Change profile picture in Firebase + Vue + Quasar Framework

Tags: vue.js, firebase-storage, vuex, quasar-framework

I'm trying to change a user's profile picture when a save button is clicked, my template looks like this:

```
<q-file
  v-model="file"
  label="Pick one file"
  class="text-center"
  use-chips
  accept=".jpg, image/*"
  style="width: 200px"
 />
   <q-btn flat class="text-primary" @click="saveUsersProfile(file)">
     Save
   </q-btn>
```

In My Script section:

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "profile",
  data: () => ({
    file: null
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapActions("store", ["saveUsersProfile"])
  },
```

Store.js

```
//Let users change Profile Picture
  saveUsersProfile({}, payload) {
    // Get the File
    const file = payload[0];
    const extension = file.name.split(".").pop();
    const uploadDate = new Date();
    const fileName = `${firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid}-${uploadDate.toDateString()}.${extension}`;
    firebaseStorage
      .ref(`users/profile/${fileName}`)
      .put(file)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Console Errors:

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Store.saveUsersProfile (store.js?07a4:122)
```

I don't know why it couldn't get the file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the `saveUsersProfile` action using `mapActions`, but without mapping it. Basically, it means that your actions will be called **with no payload** (it will be set to `{}` i believe). Thus, `payload[0]` evaluates to `undefined`. When trying to call `.name`, it throws this error you got.

You need to *map* your action.

From [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/611):

> mapActions will just, map actions.
>
> It creates shorthands for you, and you call the methods like any other normal methods.
>   after `...mapActions('auth', ['login'])`
>
> `this.$store.dispatch('auth/login', yourPayload)`
>
> is equal to
>
> `this.login(yourPayload)`

In your case, you have to add a method in your script session:

```js
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "profile",
  data: () => ({
    file: null
  }),
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("store", ["saveUsersProfile"]),

    saveUsersProfile({name}),
},
```

and for the store:

```js
//Let users change Profile Picture
  saveUsersProfile({}, payload) {
    // Get the File
    const file = payload; // I don't understand why you need [0], but maybe I'm wrong
    const extension = file.name.split(".").pop();
    ...
```

Good luck

Comment: that one is done, Thanks. but please check the error i talked about

Comment: Well, you call the `saveUsersProfile` action using `mapActions` without mapping it. Basically, it  means that your actions will be called **with no payload** (which means it will be set to `{}` i believe). Thus, `payload[0]` evaluates to `undefined`. When trying to call `.name`, it throws this error you got.

Comment: I'm trying to read the file and to get its extension. I'm confused

Comment: You're just not passing parameters as you should to your action. I edited my answer, try with this.

Comment: it now saves to firebase storage with the correct file type. Thank you